# how to pass a non line in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator, data-science

I have a dataframe as you can see below. [image]

As you can see the second row is not in this data frame. Also, there are a few more non-line in the whole dataframe. I want to reach a specific ID which I choose. And I have to make it with a loop.(not "loc" method or something like that) When I want to use "if loop", I get keyerror on number 2.

[image]

[image]

So How can I just pass the row 2 and keep going to search my ID?

Comment: Do you need to use the index at all? Or do you simply want to iterate through each row one after the other?

Comment: Please add example code for your both your loop and what you've tried to reference the rows.

Comment: @ALollz I just simply want to iterate through each row one after the other.

Comment: @ZaxR Hi, more ss are added, I hope it would be more clear my question.

Comment: Please replace your df-example and code screenshots with actual text.

Comment: @NilsWerner I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Your code is an image. Don't do that, but post the actual text instead!

Comment: @NilsWerner there is only just 3 lines code, just three!! :D . But, sure next time I will pay attention to write it as a text instead. Thank you for warning me.

Comment: I am asking you to change your posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the purpose-built [`pd.Series.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html) to iterate a series:

```
for index, val in df['_id'].items():
    print(val)
```

This method allows you to lazily iterate over (index, value) tuples.

Comment: Thank you :) here is what I exactly wanted to see